# “405 Method not allowed” on external js file in Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have small laravel project working on ajax. Below is laravel route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'location'], function(){
        Route::post('province','Api\LocationController@Province')->name('api.location.province');           
    });         
});
```

And function in controller.

```
public function Province(Request $request){
    $provicnes = Province::get();
    return response()->json($provicnes);  
}
```

I can use ajax to call from blade and I can get the correctly result. Below is ajax code.

```
var route = {
    url: "{{ url('/') }}",
    token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('api.location.province') }}",
    method:"POST",
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

Then, I create external js file and link to blade.

```
<script type="module" src="{{asset('assets/js/plugins/apps/location.js')}}"></script>
```

Then, use same the upon ajax code in jquery document-ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': route.token
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:`${route.url}/api/location/province/`,
        method:"POST",
        success:function(response){
           console.log(response)
        }
    });
});
```

But I got '`405 Method not allowed`' instead. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I solved by remove last '/' from url:`${route.url}/api/location/province/` . So it would be url:`${route.url}/api/location/province`,

Answer (score 0):

You can remove route name and simple use this line.

```
Route::post('province','Api\LocationController@Province');
```

Change your url to

```
$.ajax({
        url:`${route.url}/api/location/province/`,
        ...
    });
```

Or, assuming you have declare also the url in the route array.

```
var route = {
    url: "{{ url('/') }}",
    token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    provinceUrl: "{{ route('api.location.province') }}"

};
```

and use it in the url.

```
$.ajax({
   url:`${route.provinceUrl}`,
   ...
});
```

Comment: Dear Poldo, It may not route's name or url concern. It work inside blade view but not work once call ajax from external js file. I'm not sure is about a core-origin concern?.